# GWT. How to roll my own <ul> based menu with Event Handling?

Tags: html, gwt, widget

I use GWT 2.7. I am not happy with widgets that are default.

I would like to create a simple menu using html elements like: `<ul><li>Element</li></ul>`.
The prefered way is to use pure java, but it can be also `UiBinder`.

Please give me some help. How to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the `<li>` `Element`. Either by `getElementById()` or by `@UiField`.
 Then you sink events you want to handle:

```
Event.sinkEvents(element, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER);
```

and set the `EventListener`:

```
Event.setEventListener(element, new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        switch(event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONCLICK:
                Window.alert("Click");
                break;
            case Event.ONMOUSEOVER:
                Window.alert("Mouse over");
                break;
        }
    }
});
```